# Tutorial on creating python toolboxes?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, vba, python-toolbox

I've done the ESRI training: Creating Python Toolboxes Using ArcGIS 10.1 but is there anything more in depth? Since VBA is no longer supported in ArcMap 10 and up I'm trying to convert a cross section tool's code from VBA into python. The tool is here: http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/geoprocessing/details?entryID=C83CC388-1422-2418-7F10-B4D3DF5F1EE6 
Or if anyone knows of another way to make cross sections in arcmap that would be great.

Comment: VBA is still available in 10.2.2 you just need to install it and license it. Your local ESRI distributor upon request should provide you with a license number to activate the VBA.

Comment: For extra info for future readers : version 10.4 doesn't support VBA compatibility any more (you need to downgrade to version 10.3.1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as a tool is simple input-output python-toolboxes are great, but creating your own gui elements is not supported, drawing line is kinda possible using featureSet, but not in a user friendly way.

For more complex tools I would use the dotnet-Addin on the ArcObjects SDK, it supports both C# and VB.net: 
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/#/Building_add_ins_for_ArcGIS_for_Desktop/0001000000w2000000/

You will have buy Visual Studio and install the sdk (comes with the install package of arcgis desktop)

Comment: I have used the ArcGIS .NET C# Add-in package with Visual Studio 2010 Express, which means Visual Studio would not need to be bought.  I would think the Express version would be sufficient for the OP's needs as well.

Comment: Yes, but a lot of useful features are omitted and I assume if you have enough money to buy ESRI arcgis you have enough to buy visual studio as well.

Comment: I suppose.  My company has not, but I should pitch it to them that way...

Comment: You should, visual studio standard only one fifth of the price of one EDN ArcGIS licence.